# E: The package libgssapi-krb5-2 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: apt, package-management

I tried to install mysql-workbench but getting above error on all `sudo apt-get install` commands execution. Even tried to install `libgssapi-krb5-2` but getting below error.

```
sudo apt-get -f install libgssapi-krb5-2 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libgssapi-krb5-2 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Comment: /var/lib/dpkg/lock i removed this file while found a lock on it. May be that corrupted my package -manager

Comment: »» sudo apt-get -f install libgssapi-krb5-2 «« : The install command is `sudo apt-get update && apt install libgssapi-krb5-2`